# I have a set of Questions in a html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a set of Questions in a html form. 
Some of these questions' answers are demonstrated in Radio Buttons AND some of the questions' answers are displayed by checkboxes.

**The issue is that I want to count the answers.**
e.g. I have 5 questions. 
3 of them are Yes or No questions (radio buttons). 
2 of them are multiple choices questions (checkboxes).
The user answered 4 questions out of 5.
So, my counter will show 4 and then only submit buttons will be clickable.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">


            <p>Name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="Lname" size="50" onKeyPress="return lettersonly(event)" id="lname" value=""required/>

            </p>

            <p>E-mail:<br>
                <input type="text" name="Lemail" size="50" onKeyPress="return emailLetters(event)" value=""required/>
            </p>
            <p>Gender: 
                <input type="radio" name="Lgender" value="female" required>Female

                <input type="radio" name="Lgender" value="male" required>Male

            </p>

            <p>1. What is your special interests? <i><small>you can choose more than one option</small></i><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="Circuit Design">Circuit Design<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="System Design">System Design<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="Logical Circuits">Logical Circuits<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="IT-Security">IT-Security<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="Embedded System">Embedded System<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="q01[]" value="Others">Others<br>
            </p>

            <p>2. Have you taught Logic Circuits or other related Subjects to undergraduate students? <br>
                <input type="radio" name="q02" value="Yes" onclick="display(this)" required>Yes
                <input type="radio" name="q02" value="No" onclick="display(this)" required>No
            </p>

            <div id="hideform" style="display:none">
                <p>3. Have you taught VERILOG or other types of Gate Level programming languages to undergraduate students? <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q03" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="q03" value="No">No
                </p>

                <p>4. In your opinion, how many of students have some difficulties to cope with the concept of complex combination of Logic Units and implementation of them by a programming language like VERILOG or VHDL? <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q04" value="None of the Students">None of the Students<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q04" value="Small Group of Students">Small Group of Students<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q04" value="Half of the Students">Half of the Students<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="q04" value="Majority of the Students">Majority of the Students<br>
                </p>

                <p>5. Do you have enough time to give them enough examples during the face to face classroom? <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q05" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="q05" value="No">No
                </p>

            <p><input class= "submitbtn" type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"></p> 
            <!--onclick= "alert('Thanks for your time!')"-->
        </form>
```

Comment: Okay, that's cool! Can you show what you have already?

Comment: If you give us example of your html, we can give you working js solution and make a world better place :) Anyway, I think key word for you to google is "EventListener"

Comment: I guess you could try to have a js method which is activated every time a person click on a questions and add one to a counter variable which will activate the submit button if it value is at least 4. If you place your html I could post a more detail idea. But I guess this could be a very easy approach to solve this. Good luck

Comment: I have added the html page

Comment: you need JS code to do that

Comment: yes, I know that but I don't know how to do the javascript part as it is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need jquery (https://code.jquery.com/) to do this with less effort. Furthermore add `disabled` to your submit button so it is not clickable. Then add own JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //check form when page is loaded
  checkform();

  //check form when element is clicked
  $("input[type='radio'][name^='q'],input[type='checkbox'][name^='q']").click(function(){
    checkform();
  });
});

function checkform(){
  counter =0;
  // Count filled form sections
  for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
    if($('input[name="q0'+i+'"],input[name="q0'+i+'[]"]').is(':checked')){             
      counter++;
    }
  }

  // submit form
  if(counter>=4){
    //enable button
    $(".submitbtn").show(); //better use an id for the button
  }
}
```

Make sure there are no other input elements starting with "q" otherwise at your page my suggested code will not work. There are several ways to do that...

Comment: which jquery core do I need for it ?

Comment: Take the most recent stable one: 3.x.x, but it probably should work in all.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you that why the submit button will be disable again if i go to the next page and come back to this page again???

Comment: i need to choose one of the answers again and then the submit Button will be enabled again!

Comment: @Maziar: I have edited my solution so the form is checked every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! And if it helped so please mark my answer as the solution.